# MVC3 2 listboxes exchange items captutre changes at postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, postback

I've been reading posts for the last week on this topic and getting close but still not quite there. Any assistance would be helpful. I have a number of hyper-v servers and am trying to keep updated the guest VM assigned to it. I have two lists 1 list of assigned guest machines. 2nd a list of availale guests machines

I have the following:

ViewModel:

```
namespace MyFirstApplication.ViewModels
{
    public class HVHostGuestViewModel
    {
        public string HVCname { get; set; }
        public int AvailMemory { get; set; }
        public int AvailDisk { get; set; }
        public SelectList HVGuests {get; set; }
        public SelectList AvailGuests { get; set; }
        public List<string> GuestsRemoved { get; set; }
        public List<string> GuestsAdded { get; set; }
        public string HVComments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Manage(int id)
    {
        tblHVHost tblhvhost = db.tblHVHosts.Find(id);
        var AssignedComputers = (from c in db.tblComputers
                                  where (c.tblHVHostHVHostId == id  && c.HostName !    = "DTR")
                                  orderby(c.HostName)
                                  select c).ToList();

        var UnAssignedComputers = (from c in db.tblComputers
                                   where c.tblHVHostHVHostId == 1 && c.HostName != "DTR"
                                   orderby(c.HostName)
                                   select c).ToList();

     var GuestVM = new SelectList(AssignedComputers,"tblHVHostHVHostId","HostName");
     var AvailVM = new SelectList(UnAssignedComputers, "tblHVHostHVHostId","HostName");



        var HVViewModel = new HVHostGuestViewModel
        {
           HVCname = tblhvhost.HVCName,
           AvailDisk = 1000,
           AvailMemory = 32,
           HVComments = tblhvhost.HVComments,
          HVGuests = GuestVM,
          AvailGuests = AvailVM                
        };

        return View(HVViewModel);

    }
    //
    // POST:/HVHost/Manage/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Manage(HVHostGuestViewModel HVViewModel)
    {


        return View();
    }
```

View: (using Razor engine)

### Assign VM to Hyper-V server

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "HVHost", FormMethod.Post)){

<table>

    <tr>          
        <th> Assigned Machines </th>
        <th></th>
        <th> Available Machines</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ListBox("Guests", Model.HVGuests)
        </td>

        <td>
              <input id="MoveRight" type="button" value=" >> " />
            <br />
              <input id="MoveLeft" type="button" value=" << " />
        </td>

        <td>
             @Html.ListBox("Available", Model.AvailGuests) 

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
         <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick =" " /> </td>
         <td></td>

    </tr>
</table>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GuestsRemoved)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GuestsAdded)
```

}

Jquery script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#MoveRight,#MoveLeft").click(function (event) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr("id");
        var selectFrom = id == "MoveRight" ? "#Guests" : "#Available";
        var moveTo = id == "MoveRight" ? "#Available" : "#Guests";

        var selectedItems = $(selectFrom + " :selected").toArray();
        $(moveTo).append(selectedItems);
        selectedItems.remove;
        var name = $(event.target).attr("Text");

        $("#GuestsRemoved").val("MPE999")
        $("#GuestsAdded").val("mpe111")

    })
});
```

What is working: I get two lists and am able to move items between the two (left to right/right to left). This is using a jQuery script I found.

So far from what I've read I have two options: 1 postback to server after each event. 2) stay client side, keep a list of selected items in hidden fields which are available to the controller at post back.
I decided to try option 2.
I added two elements to my view model: GuestsRemoved, GuestsAdded as list
I addd those elements to my view using Razor helper syntax: @html.HiddenFor(model => model.guestsRemoved) & @Html.HiddenFor(Model => model.GuestsAdded).
Next, I added it to my Jquery script. I verified that values will return to the controller by assigning a test value to it: $("#GuestsAdded").val("mpe111")

So here's where I'm stuck. I have not be able to figure out the proper property that gives the "HostName", which is what I'm trying to return. A list of host names in this instance.

The raw html looks like: 
< select id="Guests" multiple="multiple" name="Guests"> MPE123

The selectlist object is:
var GuestVM = new SelectList(AssignedComputers,"tblHVHostHVHostId","HostName")

I can't figure out how to get to the "Hostname". 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`var listOfHostNHames = $(selectFrom + " :selected").text();`

Comment: Thanks Stan for the help. It's not working but I think I'm heading in the right direction. I'm still learning jQuery. Can you explain this line to me?  var selectFrom = id == "MoveRight" ? "#Guests" : "#Available";  I'm not getting the "= id == ".. is it an "if" or conditional statement?  thanks..

Comment: this is using a 'ternary' operator - you should read up on this.  basically, it is a short way of writing if/then/else.  Your example says '_if `id` is equal to "MoveRight" then return the string "#Guests" else return the string "#Available"_'.  Because the result of this operation is being assigned to `selectFrom`, after this operation `selectFrom` will be either "#Guests" or "#Available".